# How to apply this code to my audio

Tags: javascript, audio

edit* I did this:

```
   if (vol > 0) {
     vol -= 0.05;
     document.getElementById("introMusic").volume = vol;
   }
```

I got this error: Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 preGameContentObject.js:102
(anonymous function). It decreases in sound untill it is very low, then keeps playing.

i've never done audio with javaScript and am very noob. This question is almost embarrassing. I found this great function on this website to fade out my opening song for my pong game.

I start the music with this function:

```
setUpGame: function() {
        this.setUpPaddles();
        this.setUpBall("left");
        preGameContent.getMouseHover();
        preGameContent.drawButtons();
        preGameContent.getMouseClick();
        document.getElementById('introMusic').play();
    },
```

Is that best practice? It works.

I would like to know how to apply this function to my code:

```
// Initial volume of 0.20
// Make sure it's a multiple of 0.05
var vol = 0.20;
var interval = 200; // 200ms interval

var fadeout = setInterval(
  function() {
    // Reduce volume by 0.05 as long as it is above 0
    // This works as long as you start with a multiple of 0.05!
    if (vol > 0) {
      vol -= 0.05;
      audio.setVolume(vol);
    }
    else {
      // Stop the setInterval when 0 is reached
      clearInterval(fadeout);
    }
  }, interval);
```

I know where to call it, because i have an "if play game button clicked - start game" type of function that works, and i would pop it in there. Where do i reference it to my "introMusic" element ID? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went for this instead because it had no error (it needs to be refactored slightly):

```
function fadeVolume(volume, callback)
                    {
                        var factor  = 0.02,
                            speed   = 50;
                        if (volume > factor)
                        {
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                fadeVolume((document.getElementById("introMusic").volume -= factor), callback);         
                            }, speed);
                        } else {
                            (typeof(callback) !== 'function') || callback();
                        }
                    }
                    fadeVolume(document.getElementById("introMusic").volume, function(){
                        console.log('fade complete');
                        document.getElementById("introMusic").pause();
                        document.getElementById("introMusic").currentTime = 0;
                    });
```

To stop the audio i used `.pause();` and reset the current time, because `.stop();` did not work. Does anyone know why? Thanks.